Why does `$content.AppendChild($desc)` inside function make the script fail? Inlining the function makes the script run fine
We have D:\temp\Foo.xml
<Project>
  <Enable>true</Enable>
</Project>

And the following PowerShell script
function CreateContent {
    # Doesn't fix error
    # [OutputType([System.Xml.XmlNode])]
    # param()

    $content = $xml.CreateElement("Content")
    $content.InnerText = "Created inside function"
    Write-Host "Type before: $($content.GetType())" # prints "Type before: System.Xml.XmlElement"
    $desc = $xml.CreateElement("Description")
    $content.AppendChild($desc) # this is line 10; script runs fine w/o this line; why does including this line cause error on line 33?
    Write-Host "Type after: $($content.GetType())" # prints "Type after: System.Xml.XmlElement"

    # None of these lines fix the error
    # return $content
    return [System.Xml.XmlNode]$content
    # Write-Output $content
}

$file = "D:\tmp\Foo.xml"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $file

# w/o function
$content1 = $xml.CreateElement("Content")
$content1.InnerText = "Created outside function"
$desc1 = $xml.CreateElement("Description1")
$content1.AppendChild($desc1)
$xml.Project.AppendChild($content1)

# w/ function
$content2 = CreateContent
# [System.Xml.XmlNode] $content2 = CreateContent # tried this to fix error on line 33, but this causes a different error
$xml.Project.AppendChild($content2) # this is line 33; causes error

$xml.Save($file)

The script creates $xml and should modify it by appending
  <Content>Created outside function<Description1 /></Content>
  <Content>Created inside function<Description1 /></Content>

to the <Project> element of D:\tmp\Foo.xml, but it fails on line 33 with error
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.Object[]", for "AppendChild" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" 
value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."
At D:\scripts\FunOutType.ps1:33 char:1
+ $xml.Project.AppendChild($content2) # this is line 33; causes error
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

After execution D:\tmp\Foo.xml has contents
<Project>
  <Enable>true</Enable>
  <Content>Created outside function<Description1 /></Content>
</Project>

However, the script does not fail if we comment out line 10
    $content.AppendChild($desc) # this is line 10; script runs fine w/o this line; why does including this line cause error on line 33?

Also, notice that we do the exact same thing outside the function as we do inside the function
# w/o function
$content1 = $xml.CreateElement("Content")
$content1.InnerText = "Created outside function"
$desc1 = $xml.CreateElement("Description1")
$content1.AppendChild($desc1)
$xml.Project.AppendChild($content1)

and doing so outside the function does not cause any errors.

So why does putting the above excerpt inside a function cause the script to fail? Why is line 10 problematic and how to fix it?
$content.AppendChild($desc) within the function is having some kind of side-effect that does not happen with the equivalent $content1.AppendChild($desc1) outside the function, but I can't figure out what.
Thanks for any help!

Yes, moving line 33 within the function makes the script run w/o error, but I need that line outside the function.

"In PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.". In other words: your CreateContent function leaks the result of the $content.AppendChild($desc) method (which isn't an System.Xml.XmlNode type) to $content2. Try: $null = $content.AppendChild($desc). See also: stackoverflow.com/a/74717663/1701026

Thanks that explains it! Thanks for the link! Checked the type of $content2 -- it's a System.Object[]. So is $content2 = CreateContent an array containing the outputs of CreateContent when function CreateContent leaks more than one output? In general, how do you tell if a function is leaking outputs? If the function output is a System.Object[] where you expected a non-array output? The function leaked multiple outputs to the caller $content2, but does the call $content2 = CreateContent leak output to the terminal, or no because the output is captured in $content2?

I see the Show-Output function in the link, but in general, is there another way to know which statements or expressions produce output? Is there a convention? Coming from other languages, $o.AppendChild which modifies the caller $o feels like it should produce output.

No,  there is no easy way to know this (other than checking the documentation of the concerned method or just checking the method). Even a method with the same name from two different classes (as e.g. the Add method of the ArrayList class and the List<T> class) might act differently in this way. Btw, there is no harm to prefix the command with $null = (or [void]) if you aren't sure.

At first this PowerShell feature might seems strange, but if get more used to it, you might even call it a thing of beauty - and one its greatest strengths.
